# VTK export of MODFLOW 6 data sets using Flopy?

Tags: vtk, flopy

I know that Flopy can export VTK files from a MF2005 dataset (e.g. [flopy3_vtk_export.ipynb](https://github.com/modflowpy/flopy/blob/develop/examples/Notebooks/flopy3_vtk_export.ipynb)), however I tried to get that example to work with a MODFLOW 6 dataset and a few code edits, but had no success.

Does Flopy actually support VTK export from MODFLOW 6 datasets, or is that functionality just not available yet?

**In response to Sarah Leray's reply:**
I tried to use the vtk.export_heads function and found that the model object seemed to be expecting a number of attributes that didn't exist in the MF6 formulation. Did you face this problem, and if so how did you resolve it? Modified source code?

```
import os
import sys
try:
    import flopy
except:
    fpth = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..', '..'))
    sys.path.append(fpth)
    import flopy

from flopy.export import vtk

sim_name = "example_model"
sim_path = os.path.join("data", "flopy_mf6_tutorial")
heads_file_name = sim_name + ".hds"
heads_file = os.path.join(sim_path, heads_file_name)
head_output_folder = os.path.join(sim_path, "heads")

# load the simulation
loaded_sim = flopy.mf6.MFSimulation.load(sim_name, 'mf6', 'mf6', sim_path)

#export VTK heads
vtk.export_heads(loaded_sim, heads_file, head_output_folder, smooth=False, kstpkper=[(0,0)], point_scalars=False, nanval=-999.99)
```

...and I get an '*attribute error: verbose'* because verbose doesn't exist in mf6.MFSimulation (but does in the equivalent modflow.Modflow used when exporting from MF2005 etc). I forced verbose to False just to get the code to progress, then there is an *'attribute error: modelGrid'*, which looks like a more substantial and complicated missing attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to export the results of a modflow 6 model in vtk format. The routines exist (vtk.export_heads, vtk.export_model, etc). You can check these pages:
https://flopy.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.2/source/flopy.export.vtk.html
https://flopy.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.2/source/flopy.export.utils.html

Unfortunately, I faced extremely long computation times. I have a two million mesh model and it takes hours. For now, it's crippling

Let me know if you find a way to reduce export times!

Comment: Thanks Sarah, much appreciate the reply! I tried to use the vtk.export_heads function and found that the model object seemed to be expecting a number of attributes that didn't exist in the MF6 formulation. Did you face this problem, and if so how did you resolve it? Modified source code? I have edited my question to include details related to this!

Answer (score 0):

```
# load the simulation
loaded_sim = flopy.mf6.MFSimulation.load(sim_name, 'mf6', 'mf6', sim_path)

#export VTK heads
vtk.export_heads(loaded_sim, heads_file, head_output_folder, smooth=False, kstpkper=[(0,0)], point_scalars=False, nanval=-999.99)
```

It looks like you're exporting the simulation, try export the simulation instead, you can use a line like this:

```
vtk.export_model(loaded_sim.get_model(), head_output_folder)
```